# Free online video editor to add pictures

Tags: gratis, web-apps, video, video-editing

I'm looking for a simple free online video editor that:

- works on Chrome
- can add pictures to a video (no need for fancy transitions)
- can cut out pieces within the video (alternatively just merge videos to one)
- adds no watermark
- allows me to download the video to my computer

I had a hard time finding something like this. But last time I had to edit a video I actually found a tool like this, but I can't remember the site.

Keep in mind, that it needs to be a website. No software, that I need to install. I now used [wevideo](https://www.wevideo.com/), but it adds a watermark and is actually too powerful. Best would be a tool, that fits the above criteria and does nothing more. If it helps: I don't need to mess with the audio at all. I'll remove it later.

Comment: If you're willing to lose the last criteria, Youtube actually has an in-built video editor that fulfils the other requirements.

Comment: @Huey I thought you can even download it from YouTube again, after posting. I thought about that, but I don't want to use my existing Google-Account and Google makes it hard to create a "fake" Account. There must be something else out there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [YouTube Editor](https://www.youtube.com/editor).

It has all the requirements you mentioned above and if you want to download a video to your PC just add an `ss` (like `www.ssyoutube.com/…`) before the link and it will redirect you to the download page itself.

And I guess it's not that hard to make a fake account too, you just need an alternative email address to verify you and this [10 Minute Mail](http://10minutemail.com/10MinuteMail/) can help you with that. It will provide you with a temporary email on his website and then use it for Google.

Comment: Just tried to create an account. I'm aware of similar services like 10 Minute Mail. But Google even needs a **phone number** for verification. Is there something similar for text messages? [Decoy Digits](http://www.decoydigits.com/) doesn't seem to work right now.

Comment: Update: Doesn't even work with a fake Decoy Digits number. Google says `This phone number cannot be used for verification.`